# Target machine refused connection

Tags: python-3.x, geopy, nominatim

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('#######.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
geolocator = Nominatim(timeout=60)

for i in range(2,1810):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 1
    address = str(ws['B'+str(i)].value)
    city = str(ws['C'+str(i)].value)
    state = str(ws['D'+str(i)].value)
    zipc = str(ws['F'+str(i)].value)
    result = None
    iden1 = address + ' ' + city + ' ' + state
    iden2 = city + ' ' + zipc + ' ' + state
    iden3 = city + ' ' + state
    print(iden1, iden2, iden3)
    print(geolocator.geocode(iden2).address)
    try:
        location1 = geolocator.geocode(iden1)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        location2 = geolocator.geocode(iden2)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        location3 = geolocator.geocode(iden3)
    except:
        pass
    count = None
    try:
        county1 = str(location1.address)
        county1_list = county1.split(", ")
        #print(county1_list)
        for q in county1_list:
            if 'county' in q.lower():
                if count == None:
                    count = q
    except:
        pass
    try:
        county2 = str(location2.address)
        county2_list = county2.split(", ")
        #print(county2_list)
        for z in county2_list:
            if 'county' in z.lower():
                if count == None:
                    count = z
    except:
        pass
    try:
        county3 = str(location3.address)
        county3_list = county3.split(", ")
        #print(county3_list)
        for j in county3_list:
            if 'county' in j.lower():
                if count == None:
                    count = j
    except:
        pass
    print(i, count)
    #ws['E'+str(i)] = count
    if count == 50:
        #wb.save("#####" +str(count2) +".xlsx")
        count2 += 1
        count1 = 0
```

Hello all, this code is pretty simple and uses geopy to extract county names using 3 different methods names iden1, iden2, and iden3 which are a combination of address, city, state, and zipcode. This ran fine for about 300 lines but began to repeat the same county, and after restarting the script, just spat out Nones. I put in the line print (geolocator.geocode(iden2).address) to find the error and got this error message.

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:/Users/#####/Downloads/Web content/#####/####_county.py",
>   line 19, in 
>       print(geolocator.geocode(iden2).address)   File "C:\Users#####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\osm.py",
>   line 193, in geocode
>       self._call_geocoder(url, timeout=timeout), exactly_one   File "C:\Users#####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py",
>   line 171, in _call_geocoder
>       raise GeocoderServiceError(message) geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: [WinError 10061] No connection could
>   be made because the target machine actively refused it

This script was working before but now does not. Is my IP being blocked from using goepy's database or something? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It has resumed working again and I have no idea why.

Comment: aaaaand it's no longer working HAHA! Well, it looks like I can get about 300 entries in before it stops working on me. Must be something to do with a lookup limit or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're hitting their ratelimiting. It seems that they ask that you limit your API requests to 1/second. You can take a look [here](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) for their usage  policy where they list alternatives to using their API as well as contraints.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So if I simply tell the script to wait at the end of every loop iteration, this should fix the problem, no? I believe my use of the API is within their usage policy.

Comment: Yes, if you have the script wait 1 second before making another request then it should work. Note, your script will take 1810 seconds to execute then. You might consider making it wait a little over a second just to be sure.